# how to respond from plain tcp client to MessagingTemplate's sendAndReceive

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I'm using channel-adapters (not gateways) to send data with MessagingTemplate's sendAndReceive from spring integration server to a connected nonspring client (or just telnet).

After receiving the data in the client, somewhen I want to reply data to the server and resolve that sendAndReceive-Waiting. I still want to be able to send other data to the server.

How will sendAndReceive detect a response? Right now I can send whatever I want to the server, it will assume it as a new incoming message.

Is there a predefined way, like prefixing a messageid or do I have to implement it manually by interpreting the incoming messages and somehow "resolve" the sendAndReceive-blocker?

Answer (score 0):

`MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive` is based on the `TemporaryReplyChannel` which is placed to the `MessageHeaders` and afterward some `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` just uses that header to send reply back.

Yes, the sending Thread is blocked to wait for the reply throughout that `TemporaryReplyChannel`.

Hope that can help you a bit.

All other your comment regarding TCP/IP isn't clear for me yet...